# app after google arc welder throws CertPathValidatorException

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I have developed an app using google endpoints for communication with the server (google app engine).

After running the app throug google arc welder and starting it on a windows system (via chrome) I get the following exception as soon as the app is trying to use the google endpoints:

> 09-10 05:53:11.277: E/libcommon(205): nacl_list_mappings failed with
>   errno:38 09-10 05:53:12.793: E/ABCServiceHandler(205):
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

Answer (score 1):

it was the same problem as [SSL Connection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557101/ssl-connection-not-working) 
After turning off Avast Web Protection it worked fine