# SSL Connection not working

Tags: google-chrome-arc

When I connect to a server with an official SSL certificate, i get a

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust Anchor for
>   certification path not found.

But when I run this app on an Android-phone, it works. Any solutions?
Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out myself. Avast puts it own SSL certificate and Android does not trust this.